# GCloud SDK `--filter` option appears to be case SEnsitive, docs say opposite: what am I missing?

Tags: gcloud, case-insensitive, case-sensitive

First, my `gcloud --vesion` output:

```
Google Cloud SDK 425.0.0
bq 2.0.89
core 2023.03.31
gcloud-crc32c 1.0.0
gsutil 5.21
```

Next, a GCloud command line that is doing case sensitive filtering:

```
gcloud compute images list --format="table(name,description)" --filter="description:server"
```

I've got the `wc` utility so I can easily show how using a capital `S`erver in the filter returns more results:

```
gcloud compute images list --format="table(name,description)" --filter="description:server" | wc
     10     145    1297
gcloud compute images list --format="table(name,description)" --filter="description:Server" | wc
     56     818    7713
```

The main documentation on this, [gcloud topic filters](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/filters#key), specifically the section that link jumps to, "key : *simple-pattern*", says that the case is always insensitive.

I'm wondering if there may be OS issues here?
(the OS where I'm running the SDK)

Or if there are GCloud settings I can set in my "user"?

Or is this a setting managed by my organizatizon?

---

More details:

```
gcloud compute images list --format="table(name,description)" --filter="description:server"
NAME                                     DESCRIPTION
ubuntu-pro-1604-xenial-v20231213         Canonical, Ubuntu, 16.04 LTS Pro Server, amd64 xenial pro server image built on 2023-12-13
ubuntu-pro-1804-bionic-arm64-v20231213a  Canonical, Ubuntu, 18.04 LTS Pro Server, arm64 bionic pro server image built on 2023-12-13
ubuntu-pro-1804-bionic-v20231213a        Canonical, Ubuntu, 18.04 LTS Pro Server, amd64 bionic pro server image built on 2023-12-13
ubuntu-pro-2004-focal-arm64-v20231213    Canonical, Ubuntu, 20.04 LTS Pro Server, arm64 focal pro server image built on 2023-12-13
ubuntu-pro-2004-focal-v20231213          Canonical, Ubuntu, 20.04 LTS Pro Server, amd64 focal pro server image built on 2023-12-13
ubuntu-pro-2204-jammy-arm64-v20231213a   Canonical, Ubuntu, 22.04 LTS Pro Server, arm64 jammy pro server image built on 2023-12-13
ubuntu-pro-2204-jammy-v20231213a         Canonical, Ubuntu, 22.04 LTS Pro Server, amd64 jammy pro server image built on 2023-12-13
ubuntu-pro-fips-1804-bionic-v20230530    Canonical, Ubuntu, 18.04 LTS Pro FIPS Server, amd64 bionic pro fips server image built on 2023-05-30, supports Shielded VM features
ubuntu-pro-fips-2004-focal-v20231022     Canonical, Ubuntu, 20.04 LTS Pro FIPS Server, amd64 focal pro fips server image built on 2023-10-22
```

See how the above Ubuntu entries matching "server" are also in the below results -- it is because those descriptions have ***both*** words:  "server" *and* "Server".

```
gcloud compute images list --format="table(name,description)" --filter="description:Server"
NAME                                           DESCRIPTION
sles-12-sp5-v20231108-x86-64                   SUSE, SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 12 SP5, x86_64, built on 20231108
sles-15-sp5-v20231214-arm64                    SUSE, SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 15 SP5, arm64, built on 20231214
sles-15-sp5-v20231214-x86-64                   SUSE, SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 15 SP5, x86_64, built on 20231214
sles-12-sp5-sap-v20231019-x86-64               SUSE, SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 12 SP5 for SAP, x86_64, built on 20231019
sles-15-sp2-sap-v20231214-x86-64               SUSE, SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 15 SP2 for SAP, x86_64, built on 20231214
sles-15-sp3-sap-v20231214-x86-64               SUSE, SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 15 SP3 for SAP, x86_64, built on 20231214
sles-15-sp4-sap-v20231214-x86-64               SUSE, SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 15 SP4 for SAP, x86_64, built on 20231214
sles-15-sp5-sap-v20231214-x86-64               SUSE, SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 15 SP5 for SAP, x86_64, built on 20231214
sles-sap-15-sp4-hardened-v20231214-x86-64      SUSE, SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 15 SP4 for SAP hardened with security features, x86_64, built on 20231214
sles-sap-15-sp5-hardened-v20231214-x86-64      SUSE, SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 15 SP5 for SAP hardened with security features, x86_64, built on 20231214
ubuntu-pro-1604-xenial-v20231213               Canonical, Ubuntu, 16.04 LTS Pro Server, amd64 xenial pro server image built on 2023-12-13
ubuntu-pro-1804-bionic-arm64-v20231213a        Canonical, Ubuntu, 18.04 LTS Pro Server, arm64 bionic pro server image built on 2023-12-13
ubuntu-pro-1804-bionic-v20231213a              Canonical, Ubuntu, 18.04 LTS Pro Server, amd64 bionic pro server image built on 2023-12-13
ubuntu-pro-2004-focal-arm64-v20231213          Canonical, Ubuntu, 20.04 LTS Pro Server, arm64 focal pro server image built on 2023-12-13
ubuntu-pro-2004-focal-v20231213                Canonical, Ubuntu, 20.04 LTS Pro Server, amd64 focal pro server image built on 2023-12-13
ubuntu-pro-2204-jammy-arm64-v20231213a         Canonical, Ubuntu, 22.04 LTS Pro Server, arm64 jammy pro server image built on 2023-12-13
ubuntu-pro-2204-jammy-v20231213a               Canonical, Ubuntu, 22.04 LTS Pro Server, amd64 jammy pro server image built on 2023-12-13
ubuntu-pro-fips-1804-bionic-v20230530          Canonical, Ubuntu, 18.04 LTS Pro FIPS Server, amd64 bionic pro fips server image built on 2023-05-30, supports Shielded VM features
ubuntu-pro-fips-2004-focal-v20231022           Canonical, Ubuntu, 20.04 LTS Pro FIPS Server, amd64 focal pro fips server image built on 2023-10-22
sql-2014-enterprise-windows-2016-dc-v20231213  Microsoft, SQL Server 2014 Enterprise, on Windows Server 2016 Datacenter, x64 built on 20231213
windows-server-2016-dc-core-v20231213          Microsoft, Windows Server, 2016 Datacenter Core, Server Core, x64 built on 20231213
windows-server-2016-dc-v20231213               Microsoft, Windows Server, 2016 Datacenter, Server with Desktop Experience, x64 built on 20231213
windows-server-2019-dc-core-v20231213          Microsoft, Windows Server, 2019 Datacenter Core, Server Core, x64 built on 20231213
windows-server-2019-dc-v20231213               Microsoft, Windows Server, 2019 Datacenter, Server with Desktop Experience, x64 built on 20231213
windows-server-2022-dc-core-v20231213          Microsoft, Windows Server, 2022 Datacenter Core, Server Core, x64 built on 20231213
windows-server-2022-dc-v20231213               Microsoft, Windows Server, 2022 Datacenter, Server with Desktop Experience, x64 built on 20231213
sql-2016-enterprise-windows-2016-dc-v20231213  Microsoft, SQL Server 2016 Enterprise, on Windows Server 2016 Datacenter, x64 built on 20231213
sql-2016-enterprise-windows-2019-dc-v20231213  Microsoft, SQL Server 2016 Enterprise, on Windows Server 2019 Datacenter, x64 built on 20231213
sql-2016-standard-windows-2016-dc-v20231213    Microsoft, SQL Server 2016 Standard, on Windows Server 2016 Datacenter, x64 built on 20231213
sql-2016-standard-windows-2019-dc-v20231213    Microsoft, SQL Server 2016 Standard, on Windows Server 2019 Datacenter, x64 built on 20231213
sql-2016-web-windows-2016-dc-v20231213         Microsoft, SQL Server 2016 Web, on Windows Server 2016 Datacenter, x64 built on 20231213
sql-2016-web-windows-2019-dc-v20231213         Microsoft, SQL Server 2016 Web, on Windows Server 2019 Datacenter, x64 built on 20231213
sql-2017-enterprise-windows-2016-dc-v20231213  Microsoft, SQL Server 2017 Enterprise, on Windows Server 2016 Datacenter, x64 built on 20231213
sql-2017-enterprise-windows-2019-dc-v20231213  Microsoft, SQL Server 2017 Enterprise, on Windows Server 2019 Datacenter, x64 built on 20231213
sql-2017-enterprise-windows-2022-dc-v20231213  Microsoft, SQL Server 2017 Enterprise, on Windows Server 2022 Datacenter, x64 built on 20231213
sql-2017-express-windows-2016-dc-v20231213     Microsoft, SQL Server 2017 Express, on Windows Server 2016 Datacenter, x64 built on 20231213
sql-2017-express-windows-2019-dc-v20231213     Microsoft, SQL Server 2017 Express, on Windows Server 2019 Datacenter, x64 built on 20231213
sql-2017-standard-windows-2016-dc-v20231213    Microsoft, SQL Server 2017 Standard, on Windows Server 2016 Datacenter, x64 built on 20231213
sql-2017-standard-windows-2019-dc-v20231213    Microsoft, SQL Server 2017 Standard, on Windows Server 2019 Datacenter, x64 built on 20231213
sql-2017-standard-windows-2022-dc-v20231213    Microsoft, SQL Server 2017 Standard, on Windows Server 2022 Datacenter, x64 built on 20231213
sql-2017-web-windows-2016-dc-v20231213         Microsoft, SQL Server 2017 Web, on Windows Server 2016 Datacenter, x64 built on 20231213
sql-2017-web-windows-2019-dc-v20231213         Microsoft, SQL Server 2017 Web, on Windows Server 2019 Datacenter, x64 built on 20231213
sql-2017-web-windows-2022-dc-v20231213         Microsoft, SQL Server 2017 Web, on Windows Server 2022 Datacenter, x64 built on 20231213
sql-2019-enterprise-windows-2019-dc-v20231213  Microsoft, SQL Server 2019 Enterprise, on Windows Server 2019 Datacenter, x64 built on 20231213
sql-2019-enterprise-windows-2022-dc-v20231213  Microsoft, SQL Server 2019 Enterprise, on Windows Server 2022 Datacenter, x64 built on 20231213
sql-2019-standard-windows-2019-dc-v20231213    Microsoft, SQL Server 2019 Standard, on Windows Server 2019 Datacenter, x64 built on 20231213
sql-2019-standard-windows-2022-dc-v20231213    Microsoft, SQL Server 2019 Standard, on Windows Server 2022 Datacenter, x64 built on 20231213
sql-2019-web-windows-2019-dc-v20231213         Microsoft, SQL Server 2019 Web, on Windows Server 2019 Datacenter, x64 built on 20231213
sql-2019-web-windows-2022-dc-v20231213         Microsoft, SQL Server 2019 Web, on Windows Server 2022 Datacenter, x64 built on 20231213
sql-2022-enterprise-windows-2019-dc-v20231213  Microsoft, SQL Server 2022 Enterprise, on Windows Server 2019 Datacenter, x64 built on 20231213
sql-2022-enterprise-windows-2022-dc-v20231213  Microsoft, SQL Server 2022 Enterprise, on Windows Server 2022 Datacenter, x64 built on 20231213
sql-2022-standard-windows-2019-dc-v20231213    Microsoft, SQL Server 2022 Standard, on Windows Server 2019 Datacenter, x64 built on 20231213
sql-2022-standard-windows-2022-dc-v20231213    Microsoft, SQL Server 2022 Standard, on Windows Server 2022 Datacenter, x64 built on 20231213
sql-2022-web-windows-2019-dc-v20231213         Microsoft, SQL Server 2022 Web, on Windows Server 2019 Datacenter, x64 built on 20231213
sql-2022-web-windows-2022-dc-v20231213         Microsoft, SQL Server 2022 Web, on Windows Server 2022 Datacenter, x64 built on 20231213
```